# How to calculate the capacity in a system of capacitors

Tags: capacitor

How to calculate the capacity of the capacitor "C" given that the equivalent capacity of the system of capacitors in the figure is \$C_{eq}=9.22~\mu\mathrm{F}\$. Can you tell me also the relations between the capacitors? I mean if they are in series or in parallel.

[image]

$$
\begin{align}
9.22~\mu\mathrm{F}&=\frac{\left(\frac{12~\mu\mathrm{F} \,\cdot\, 8.35~\mu\mathrm{F}}{12~\mu\mathrm{F}\,+\,8.35~\mu\mathrm{F}}+4.25~\mu\mathrm{F}\right) C}{\frac{12~\mu\mathrm{F} \,\cdot\, 8.35~\mu\mathrm{F}}{12~\mu\mathrm{F}\,+\,8.35~\mu\mathrm{F}}+4.25~\mu\mathrm{F}+C}+7.22~\mu\mathrm{F},\\
\\
C&=2.6~\mu\mathrm{F}.
\end{align}
$$

Comment: One pair at a time.

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams For example are the capacitors "7.22" and "C" in series?

Comment: Erm, no. C is in series with the rest of the network, and then that is in parallel with the 7.22uF capacitor.

Answer (score 1):

You know that the capacitance of two capacitors C1 and C2 in parallel is C1+C2.

You know that the capacitance of two capacitors C1 and C2 in series is 
\$ 1 \over {  {1 \over  C1} + {1 \over C2} }\$

You should be able to find the capacitance if the 7.22uF capacitor was not there, using the first equation.

You should be able to work out the capacitance in series with the unknown capacitance C using a combination of the two equations.

Then just re-arrange the second equation to find the value of the unknown capacitor.

Answer (score 1):

I will guide you through the process but leave the details to you. You need to apply the 2 basic combining rules for capacitors:  parallel capacitors add and series capacitors combine as the reciprocal of the sum of the reciprocals (the latter rule is the same as for parallel resistors). The 12.0 uF and the 8.35 uF capacitors are in series so apply the series capacitor rule to them.  The resultant capacitance is in parallel with the 1.25 uF capacitor so apply the parallel rule.  This resultant capacitance is in series with the unknown capacitor, C, so apply the series rule but, in this case, you will wind up with a expression containing C which represents the capacitance.  That capacitance is in parallel with the 7.22 uF capacitor so apply the parallel rule.  This will give you an expression that you can equate with the given final capacitance of 9.22 uF.  Now you have an equation that can be solved for C. It sounds complicated but if you follow the 2 capacitance combining rules, you should be able to work it out.  Good luck.

Comment: I've added to the question the "fruits" of your explanation---have I understood?

Comment: Yes, it looks like you understood it perfectly.  Good job.